# acceptable quality limit for an audit?

Tags: sample-size, sample

I have been tasked to see if there is a better audit tool than the Acceptable Quality Limit. I believe that this tool is mostly used for defects and I'm not sure if it is an accurate auditing tool for judging people and their cases.

Would it be something as easy as confidence interval? I feel like there should be more than this

The main concern I am having is that 
1) not everyone has a case every month; some employees have multiple cases in a month, others do not
2) We only have an average of 20 cases total per month
3) Each case has a lot to audit, so auditing all of them is too time consuming

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your are testing.

If its a product, why don't you use statistical process control?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control

If you have high dimensional multivariate data, you could use PCA- T2 and PCA-SPE analysis. In this technique, you can set your confidence level.